# Windows clients not accepting incoming connections on WiFi

Tags: networking, windows-7, firewall, tcp, wifi

I am having a few issues with clients in remote sites and have narrowed it down to TCP connections not being accepted by/not reaching the WiFi adapter. Outgoing connections are fine, and over Ethernet there is no problem.

The adapter is in the Domain profile for firewall and the firewall is passive. I have determined this by looking at the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security management tool. I have enabled logging for dropped packets anyway and the log remains empty.

I have tried a multitude of troubleshooting steps, including: Stopping the firewall service, network traces on both the connecting client and the adapter that should be receiving connections, starting the laptop exclusively on on WiFi, updating drivers.

I am not using DNS to make connections, just the respective IP addresses (Ethernet and WiFi). Our network team assure me there are no ACLs in place to block connections on the access points or controllers. All that can be obtained from the Wireless adapter is a ping response, so I know it's working. The adapters are both in the same DHCP pool and acquire their addresses from a local DC.

I'm out of ideas.... **Can you think of anything else I can try in order to isolate the cause of the problem?** I'm arranging for a Windows XP laptop to be tested to rule Windows 7 out and will update the question if I have any luck with that.

**EDIT:**

I sent a windows XP laptop to the site with the remote AP and it's the same story. Very strange indeed.

Comment: How about some detail on how you're trying to connect. FTP, SMB, HTTP, etc., etc.? Also, do you get any type of error message when trying to connect?

Comment: I can't connect to anything. nmap scan shows no open ports on the WiFi adapter. An example response when trying to remote manage on that adapter is "The network path was not found".

Comment: Is there any additional software running on the machine that would be blocking access?  3rd party firewall, antivirus, IPS/IDS, NAC?  Did you try shutting down the firewall completely as a test?

Comment: Removed Anti-virus and anything else like that IPSec is disabled. Disabled firewall service too. There's nothing in the way that I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ultimately the answer to my question is no, there's nothing else on the client side that could be blocking the connections.

Despite telling me that it wasn't the case, our network support team identified that the remote APs were configured with firewall rules that stopped connections being made.

Answer (score 0):

some Wireless router have a feature called client isolation that prevents wireless clients from talking to other wireless clients. check to make sure that is disabled in your wireless router.